# Store application logs inside the docker container file system

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elk, elastalert

I am running my elastalert server on a docker container using the docker compose.
Here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  elastalert:
    container_name: elastalert
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfiles/Dockerfile-elastalert
    image: elastalert:3.0.0-beta.0
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
      - 3333:3333
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./elastalert/config/elastalert.yml:/opt/elastalert/config.yaml
      - ./elastalert/config/elastalert-test.yml:/opt/elastalert/config-test.yaml
      - ./elastalert/config/config.json:/opt/elastalert-server/config/config.json
      - ./elastalert/rules:/opt/elastalert/rules
      - ./elastalert/rule_templates:/opt/elastalert/rule_templates
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:3030 || exit 1"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 15s
        retries: 3
```

The Docker file for the elastalert is:

```
FROM bitsensor/elastalert:3.0.0-beta.0

USER root

RUN apk update && \
    apk add bash curl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ADD elastalert/bin/elastalert-start.sh /usr/local/bin/
ADD elastalert/bin/elastic_search_status.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/elastalert-start.sh 
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/elastic_search_status.sh

USER node

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/elastalert-start.sh"]
```

When I am running the elastalert container I am able view the logs on the terminal using the command:
**docker-compose logs -f** but these logs are not stored anywhere inside the container (container file system).

Is there a way to store these logs inside the elastalert container?

Like */var/log/elastalert.log* in the **elastalert container file system**.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want the logs to be stored inside the container? Containers are ephemeral by nature so they come and go except if you define this as a volume.
By default though you can access the logs on this path on your HOST:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log
```

Comment: To define as a volume we need to store these logs in the container right? So, I wanted the logs to be stored inside the container. If it possible to create a volume for logs without storing them in the container can be please provide more information on it.